# Profiling all class methods

Tags: python, design-patterns

I'm reading the [Practical Python Design Patterns](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484226797) and I'm trying to learn the decorator concept. I've stuck in the last example, where I cannot get the logic of the writing a profiler that applies to all methods of a class.

[Here is at the example from the book](https://books.google.nl/books?id=gn86DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA120&lpg=PA120&dq=profile_all_class_methods&source=bl&ots=dzWx-ZsgEq&sig=bht_4MdRtQxTiabTJi7csx1TzdU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjotJbPufneAhVIZFAKHYCCA2IQ6AEwCHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=profile_all_class_methods&f=false). I didn't rewrite it here because of the copywrite restriction but I hope Google Book's link is sufficient.

The problem is, when I implement the code and apply it on my `DoMathStuff` class, I get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`. To me, the `try/except/else` part is unclear and I think there is a typo somewhere but I can tell where.

```
@profile_all_class_methods
class DoMathStuff(object):
    """docstring for DoMathStuff"""
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def fib(self):
        fPrev, f = 1, 1
        for num in xrange(2, self.n):
            fPrev, f = f, f + fPrev

        return f

    @profiling_decorator
    def fact(self):
        fct = 1
        for num in xrange(1, self.n):
            fct *= num

        return fct


if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = DoMathStuff(10)
    print("Fib = {}, Fact = {}".format(m.fib(), m.fact()))
```

Edit: And here is the error I'm getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "class_profiler.py", line 62, in <module>
    print("Fib = {}, Fact = {}".format(m.fib(), m.fact()))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback. And are you sure you have all the indentation correct? The final `return ProfiledClass` should be outside the class but inside the `def profile_all_class_methods`.

Comment: I already have the `return ProfiledClass` in the correct place as you mentioned. I also double checked and I think I've everything correctly. I understand the logic of the decorator. I see that the class is a `NoneType` but I don't understand why? Your concern is valid but I don't think that's the issue here!

Comment: There are bugs in the book, and that makes me think there is one here too. I've already fix the one in the `wrap_f` where the author referred to `n` while he shouldn't.

Comment: Can you try and call `m.fib()` and `m.fact()` separately to see which one is triggering the error?

Comment: Both triggers the error. However, if I don't decorate the class, they work just fine.

Comment: I've added the full code at the end of the question, I'll remove it later :-) I hope this helps. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is indeed full of errors. Just thinking of the flow of that `__getattribute__` method: given an attribute name, we look up the attribute on the the wrapper class (by calling the superclass implementation). If the attribute is not found there - which it isn't in the case of "fib", because it's on the wrapped class, not the wrapper - Python will raise an AttributeError. OK, we catch that, presumably so that we can then proceed to look it up on the wrapped class. But what do we do in the except clause? Nothing. The code is for some reason in the else clause, which is only called when the exception was *not* raised.

So if we fixed that by removing the `pass` and moving the code from the `else` block, what then? Well, this now wants to get `self.inst`, ie the instance of the wrapped class. But guess what, getting an attribute will call the `__getattribute__` method. So we recurse. Now, the original call to get the `inst` attribute will succeed. We assign it to `x`. Now what? Er, nothing. We exit without returning x. So the original call gets None for the value of `self.inst`, and tries to call `__getattribute__` on that - so we'll get another AttributeError.

Quite frankly, this code looks like it was written by someone who doesn't really know Python very well. It *would* be possible to fix it by, in addition to the change above, returning the value of the superclass call instead of assigning it:

```
def __getattribute__(self, s):
    try:
        return super(ProfiledClass, self).__getattribute__(s)
    except AttributeError:
        x = self.inst.__getattribute__(s)
        if type(x) == type(self.__init__):
            return profiling_decorator(x)
        else:
            return x
```

but this is still pretty bad code. For a start, you should never call double-underscore methods directly, so the line after the except should be `x = getattr(self.inst, s)`. But the problems are deeper than that; `__getattribute__` is entirely the wrong method to override in the first place. That method is called for all attribute lookups, hence the complicated try/super/except stuff. But Python gives you a method that is only called when an attribute is *not* directly found, which is `__getattr__`. Defining that instead would allow you to completely remove most of the code:

```
def __getattr__(self, s):
    x = getattr(self.inst, s)
    if type(x) == type(self.__init__):
        return profiling_decorator(x)
    else:
        return x
```

(And if I was being really picky, I'd replace that `type(x) == type(self.__init__)` stuff with just `if callable(x)`.)

And the final mistake in this code is that they've left `factorial` decorated explicitly, when the whole point of the code is that the methods will be decorated automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I could have seen that something is wrong but I couldn't figure it out. I've noticed quite of a few errors in the book, so my first intuition was that there is something wrong here. Regarding the `__getattr__`, I also wondered since I've seen it in use in other examples, and then suddenly `__getattribute__` showed up and added more confusion. The decorated `factorial` is everywhere in the book, so confusing as well. Thanks again for your answer :-)